# Install-Package FluentValidation always fail

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, fluentvalidation

I want to install FluentValidation ,but I fail every time.

[image]

Comment: May i know, Why do you install fluent Api in .NEt framework .. If you install Entity framework, it will automatically take the fluent Api.

Comment: thanks your reply!I don't need Entity framework. I find the reason that the last version need framework 4.5 and My framework is 4.0.I should install low version package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last version that supported installation into a .NET 4.0 framework project was 5.5.0, so if you run the following into your project, it should work:

> Install-Package FluentValidation -Version 5.5.0